# Retrieve Postgres TSTZRANGE to PgRange<Datetime<Utc>> with Rust sqlx

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-sqlx

I have the following SQL table scheme

```sql
CREATE TABLE reservation (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    timespan TSTZRANGE
);

INSERT INTO reservation(timespan) VALUES
    (TSTZRANGE(now() + INTERVAL '0 hour', now() + INTERVAL '1 hour')),
    (TSTZRANGE(now() + INTERVAL '2 hour', now() + INTERVAL '3 hour'));
```

and using rust-sqlx, I would like to retrieve those rows directly into a struct.

```rust
/*
[dependencies]
chrono = "0.4"
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
sqlx = { version = "0.5", features = [ "runtime-tokio-native-tls" , "postgres" ] }
*/

use chrono::prelude::*;
use sqlx::FromRow;
use sqlx::postgres::{types::PgRange, PgPoolOptions};


#[derive(Debug, FromRow)]
struct Reservation {
    id: i32,
    timespan: PgRange<DateTime<Utc>>,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), sqlx::Error> {
    let db_url: String = "postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost/mydb".to_owned();

    let pool = PgPoolOptions::new()
        .max_connections(2)
        .connect(&db_url)
        .await?;

    let select_query = sqlx::query_as::<_, Reservation>("SELECT id, timespan FROM reservation");
    let reservations: Vec<Reservation> = select_query.fetch_all(&pool).await?;

    dbg!("{:?}", reservations);

    Ok(())
}
```

I am getting the following 2 following errors

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `PgRange<chrono::DateTime<chrono::Utc>>: Type<_>` is not satisfied
...
...
error[E0277]: the trait bound `chrono::DateTime<chrono::Utc>: Type<Postgres>` is not satisfied
```

How do I go about manually implementing these trait bounds? or is there a simpler way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Newbie mistake! I just had to add chrono flag for sqlx in Cargo.toml

```ini
sqlx = { version = "0.5", features = [ "runtime-tokio-native-tls" , "postgres" , "chrono" ] }
```